# Autowiring a interface work without annotating it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, annotations

I am working on Spring and hibernate project. For database communication we have conventional two layered implementation (i.e DAO layer and Service layer). I have following files:

DemoDao.java

```
package net.dao;
import java.util.List;
import net.domain.Demo;
public interface DemoDao 
{
 public List<Demo> get();
}
```

DemoDaoImpl.java

```
package net.dao;

import java.util.List;  

import net.domain.Demo;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class DemoDaoImpl implements DemoDao
{
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public List<Demo> get()
    {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<Demo> list=session.createQuery("from Demo").list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

That was DAO layer

Follwing is from service layer:

DemoManager.java

```
package net.service;

import java.util.List;

import net.domain.Demo;

public interface DemoManager 
{
    public List<Demo> get();
}
```

DemoManagerImpl.java

```
package net.service;

import java.util.List;

import net.dao.DemoDao;
import net.domain.Demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DemoManagerImpl implements DemoManager 
{
    @Autowired
    DemoDao demoDao;
    public List<Demo> get()
    {
        List<Demo> list=demoDao.get();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Follwing is my controller

FromDualLayerView.java

```
package net.spring;

import java.util.List;

import net.domain.Demo;
import net.service.DemoManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class FromDualLayerView 
{
    @Autowired
    DemoManager demoManager;

    @RequestMapping("/dualLayer")
    public ModelAndView toResult(ModelMap map)
    {
        List<Demo> list=demoManager.get();
        map.addAttribute("listData", list);
        return new ModelAndView("result");
    }
}
```

**My Question**

Actually everything works fine, but my question over here is that i am not annotating the DemoDao and DemoManager interface, but i am autowiring them. According to the autowiring definition the entities which are annotated are injected.

**The how come the dependency is injected by Spring container?**

And how does it work like an Impl class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is you reference your package somewhere for Spring to look for Bean annotations. By the `@Controller`, `@Service` etc annotations they get registered as Beans to Spring and can then be autowired to other beans

Comment: Ya that true I do that, but what I have annotated with @Service and what I am autowiring is two different things, yet it woks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DemoManagerImpl is annotated as a service and is the only qualifying bean to be injected in the FromDualLayerView class, as it's the only component which is instance of DemoManager. I suppose you have the component scan turned on as well.

Comment: So any instance of DemoManager which is qualified will be injected, will be injected, right?

Comment: Any, if it's only one. Otherwise you will get an error that there more qualifying beans for autowire. In that case you can use @Inject and use names for beans.

Comment: Ok, I got my answer. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

The @Repository annotation and the @Service annotation mean you are annotating them. It's actually a spring best practice to annotate the implementations and not the interfaces.

Your spring config file is scanning the classpath, thus those beans are detected. Turn spring logging up to TRACE and you'll probably see output along the lines of:

"scanning classpath, found target DemoDaoImpl"

Comment: Ya but I am not annotating the interfaces but auto wiring them.And I am not actually autowiring the Impl classes. How does that work?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html

Comment: You are not understanding my question here. The classes are annotated and dependencies are injected, everything is working fine. But I am autowiring a interface which I have not annotated, yet the dependency is injected.

Comment: The spring engine works roughly like this: the scanner sees the 'Autowired' and says 'do I have any beans that match the type DemoManager?'. Spring looks through its registered beans and finds a match because DemoDaoImpl implements the type DemoManager. 'Autowired' specifies the type that must be injected, 'Repository' specifies that DemoDaoImpl can be injected. Make a dummy DemoDaoImplTwo class and look at the error message when you try to run this.

Comment: Ok, I get what you are saying. But if somehow I want that other DemoDaoImplTwo class implementing DemoDao, than is it possible to handle both of them, and tell spring which one to inject at runtime?

Comment: Yes, in that case you use the @Qualifier annotation and refer to the bean by name rather than type.